# jQuery TaxCloud Lookup API origin city missing

Tags: jquery, http

I'm trying to use the Lookup API in TaxCloud. I believe I've successfully made the call with jQuery post(), however, the response from the API tells me the origin city is missing, which I did include in my origin address. I tested the API in Postman with the same data, and it is working. But how do I get it to work in my website?

data: 

`var data = {
    'apiLoginId': 'XXXXX',
    'apiKey': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'customerID': 'Customer',
    'cartItems': [
                    {
                        'Qty': 1,
                        'Price': 10,
                        'TIC': '00000',
                        'ItemID': '8LA06052',
                        'Index': 0
                    }
                ],
    'origin': {
                    'Address1': '423 7th Street',
                    'City': 'San Francisco',
                    'State': 'CA',
                    'Zip5': '94132'
                },
    'destination': {
                    'Address1': '1238 Salisbury Street',
                    'City': 'West Lafayette',
                    'State': 'IN',
                    'Zip5': '47906'
                }
};`

jQuery POST request:

```
$.post('https://api.taxcloud.com/1.0/TaxCloud/Lookup', data, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading. The actual error is that TaxCloud isn’t seeing any of your nested elements because you need to JSON.Stringify compound/complex objects for descendants past the first level to make it through. Try this slight revision:

```
$.post('https://api.taxcloud.com/1.0/TaxCloud/Lookup',
    JSON.stringify(data),
    function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    'json');
```

Comment: I've tried this method, and then it returns me an error of 'API ID is missing'. I did include an API ID and when I try it in Postman it works. Does this mean the POST body is not found then?